# Python not logging to stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-logging

I have a simple YAML configuration for the logger:

```
simple-logger:
  version: 1
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s %(message)s'
      datefmt: '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      stream: ext://sys.stdout
```

In the factory that initializes the application, I use dictConfig to initialize the configuration:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config.get_attribute("simple-logger"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("Initializing...")
```

The issue is, I'm not getting any output in the terminal. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I have to explicitly tell the root to use the console handler.

```
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

Solved the issue.